# Why do I get a 0x1 cell? Matlab what function

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm using the following code to look through all files in a particular directory, and I'm getting some strange results.  The point of the program is to do the following: I'm looking through a huge number (~7000+) of .mat files for each day between 6-20-2007 and 9-20-2007.  What I'm looking to do is search through each of these folders and look at the .mat files, etc.  However, for some reason I'm getting a 0x1 cell that doesn't make sense to me.  Maybe someone with a better trained eye can see why?

```
jDate = strtok( dates(j).name, '.' );    % Or dates(j,1).name

tradeFolder = sprintf( 'TAQ Data\\trades unzipped\\%s.tar\\%s\\', jDate );    
tradeFiles = what(tradeFolder);
tradeMat = tradeFiles.mat;

quoteFolder = sprintf( 'TAQ Data\\quotes unzipped\\%s.tar\\%s\\', jDate );
quoteFiles = what(quoteFolder);
quoteMat = quoteFiles.mat;
```

(I have excluded the beginnings of the file paths since it includes my name).  Anyways, how the data is saved is this: I extracted each day's worth of data and saved it to the folders listed above.  Inside trades unzipped, for instance, will be a folder 20070620.tar, and inside that folder will be another folder named 20070620, and inside that folder is over 7000 .mat files.  So....how come I'm getting a 0x1 cell for the tradeFiles.mat?

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments

1. Both `sprintf` lines you have (`tradeFolder=...` and `quoteFolder=...`) has two `'%s'` in the formatted string, while only one argument: `jDate`. This might cause undefined behavior.
2. It is better to use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to concatenate paths and file names.
3. Although using `what` in this context is correct, you might want to double-check it using `dir( fullfile( tradeFolder, '*.mat' ) );`
4. It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Hey thanks.  It turns out point #1 was it.  My logic was that I wanted both '%s' to be jDate, so I only used it once.  But that's where it was wrong.  I used jDate twice and now it gives me exactly what I expected.  Thanks for having a look at it. :)